# Key-indexed search in existence tables

Tags: c

I have a doubt about one of my book's statement.

Talking about key-indexed search in a symbol table, at a certain point it says: "*If there aren't records (but only keys), we can use a bit table. In this case, the symbol table is called existence table, because we can consider the k-th bit as an indicator whether the k key there is or there isn't in the table. For example, using a 313-word table on a 32-bit computer, we can use this method to quickly determine whether a given 4-digit internal telephone number was already assigned.*"

Well, I know what a word is, thus that existence table should be a 10.016-bit table, in that case. But what does it mean? What does that fact of the 4-digit telephone number have to do with it? And so, how you can implement a symbol table with key-indexed search, when the records correspond to the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 9000 four-digit numbers (in base 10, decimal), and 10000 (nonnegative) numbers with at most four digits, so a table with more than 10,000 bits is sufficient to indicate for each of these numbers whether it's present (is bit no `n` set or not?). For five-digit numbers - 90,000 of them - you'd need a larger table.

Since the bit-table can only tell you either "yes, we have it" or "no, we haven't", you can't use it if you need any information exceeding that. But if that's all you need to know, any injective mapping of keys to indices into the table (array) gives you access to that information, compactly stored. In the case of the telephone numbers, the mapping is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bittable of 10000 bits (each bit corresponding to a phone number), which fit in 313 bytes (10000/32 = 312.5 ~= 313)